# Expand user for paths in argparse arguments

Tags: python, argparse, expanduser

I'd like to allow the user of my program to use the "~" shortcut in the arguments that are paths to some files, i.e., the "home" shortcut for linux systems. But to do so, as far as I understand, I need to all the os.path.expanduser function over each argument that is a path.

Is there a nicer way to do so, using the options provided in argparse?

Comment: I doubt, but I really wonder why you would consider a possible `argparse` solution to be nicer than a solution in the `os` module, which is indented for things related to the **o**perating **s**ystem?

Comment: Oh, I don't mean to override the os function. What I am trying to ask is whether I can invoke it through some option in argparse (something similar to the "action" option).

Comment: Sounds like something you could package in a custom `type` function.  `type` accepts any Python callable.  In fact, other than the default `None` `type`, `argparse` doesn't define any special functions.  `int`, `float` are standard Python functions.  Well there is the `argparse.FileType` that illustrates how to write a custom type factory.

Comment: sounds like an idea! I'll report back when I try it. Thanks!